# MAAS cant ssh to remote Host

Tags: ssh, maas, conjure-up

i have configured the maas and succesfully commission and deploy hosts
but i can not ssh to the hosts remotely through maas controller node
i have generated an ssh key and imported to the maas admin user, ssh is working and accepting connections before deployment but it doesnt recognize the ssh key and after the deployment i'm receiving the following error

> administrator@os-maas-cntrl:~$ ssh 172.16.103.12
>
> ssh: connect tohost 172.16.103.12 port 22: Connection refused

Could you help me with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is because your missing the username in the SSH connection.

`ssh ubuntu@172.16.103.12`

Answer (score 0):

i have tried both ways with or without username, the authentication method is public key, the problem is it's not accepting any ssh requests if it would be username error i believe i should at least access through ssh and rejected

here is the maas version i'm using

```
administrator@os-maas-cntrl:~$ dpkg --list | grep maas
ii  maas                               2.1.2+bzr5555-0ubuntu1~16.04.1      all          "Metal as a Service" is a physical cloud and IPAM
ii  maas-cli                           2.1.2+bzr5555-0ubuntu1~16.04.1      all          MAAS client and command-line interface
ii  maas-common                        2.1.2+bzr5555-0ubuntu1~16.04.1      all          MAAS server common files
ii  maas-dhcp                          2.1.2+bzr5555-0ubuntu1~16.04.1      all          MAAS DHCP server
ii  maas-dns                           2.1.2+bzr5555-0ubuntu1~16.04.1      all          MAAS DNS server
ii  maas-proxy                         2.1.2+bzr5555-0ubuntu1~16.04.1      all          MAAS Caching Proxy
ii  maas-rack-controller               2.1.2+bzr5555-0ubuntu1~16.04.1      all          Rack Controller for MAAS
ii  maas-region-api                    2.1.2+bzr5555-0ubuntu1~16.04.1      all          Region controller API service for MAAS
ii  maas-region-controller             2.1.2+bzr5555-0ubuntu1~16.04.1      all          Region Controller for MAAS
ii  python3-django-maas                2.1.2+bzr5555-0ubuntu1~16.04.1      all          MAAS server Django web framework (Python 3)
ii  python3-maas-client                2.1.2+bzr5555-0ubuntu1~16.04.1      all          MAAS python API client (Python 3)
ii  python3-maas-provisioningserver    2.1.2+bzr5555-0ubuntu1~16.04.1      all          MAAS server provisioning libraries (Python 3)
```

i can ssh to the host before deploying and its rejecting my connections,
i have created an ssh key and uploaded it to the maas admin user and deployed the machine through this admin user.

i'm trying to implement openstack environment with maas base and i'm currently using virtual machines deployed in vmware, maas can currently deploy and configure remote machines so there is no problem in this section. however when trying to deploy openstack it fails becouse it can not reach the machines through ssh and timeout.

```
administrator@os-maas-cntrl:~$ dpkg --list | grep juju
ii  juju-2.0                           1:2.1~beta4-0ubuntu1~16.04.1~juju1  amd64        Juju is devops distilled - client
administrator@os-maas-cntrl:~$ dpkg --list | grep conjure-up
ii  conjure-up                         2.1.0-0~201701041302~ubuntu16.04.1  all          Package runtime for conjure-up spells
```

Comment: if you want to add more information, edit your question instead of posting an answer to it.